# My nested anchor tags won't nest?

Tags: php

I'm trying to build my site's navigation using recursion and I can't seem to get the `<div>` tags to nest properly. I'm not even sure if this code is the path I should go down, but It's a start. The desired output:

```
<div class="parent">1</div>
<div class="child">
    <a href="#">1.1</a>
    <a href="#">1.2</a>
    <a href="#">1.3</a>
</div>

<div class="parent">2</div>
<div class="child">
    <a href="#">2.1</a>
    <a href="#">2.2</a>
    <a href="#">2.3</a>
</div>
```

Here is my database:

[image]

Here's the code I'm trying to get working: (THIS CODE NEEDS A LOT OF WORK)

```
/* here's the call */
$this->buildNav($array,NULL,false);

private function buildNav($array,$parent,$loop)
{
    $html = '';
    $class = ($loop) ? 'child' : 'parent';
    $tag   = '<div>%s</div>';
    $child = false; 
    foreach($array as $item)
    {
        if($item['parent']===$parent)
        {
            $child = true;
            $html .= '<div>'.$item['category_name'];
            $html .= $this->buildNav($array,$item['category_id'],true);
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '<a href="#">'.$item['category_name'].'</a>';
        }
        if(!$child)
        {
            $tag = '';
        }
    }
    return sprintf($tag,$html);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Per shapeshifter's advice I went away from recursion and just called a function to get the children ... beautiful idea ;) Here's the code:

```
private function buildNav($array,$parent)
{
    $html = '';
    foreach($array as $item)
    {
        if($item['parent'] === NULL)
        {
            $html .= '<div class="parent">'.$item['category_name'].'</div>';
            $html .= '<div class="child">'.$this->getChildren($array,$item['category_id']).'</div>';
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
private function getChildren($array,$parent)
{
    $html = '';
    foreach($array as $item)
    {
        if($item['parent']===$parent)
        {
            $html .= '<a href="#">'.$item['category_name'].'</a>';
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Thanks again to the others who provided such profound alternatives and or direction ;)

Comment: You should post the actual code. As it stands, there are syntax errors.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for the heads up. I had the anchor tag all messed up ... it's fixed now ;)

Comment: "THIS CODE NEEDS A LOT OF WORK" (you should post this question once you've done that work on it, not before)

Comment: _"I can't seem to get the `<div>` tags to nest properly"_ in your example output, your `<div>`s _aren't nested_.

Comment: You don't need recursion here, your going one level deep.  Try loop through all with parent id = NULL then call a function that prints the child div.

Comment: Man I guess I've totally screwed this post up! LOL

Comment: Eric, thanks for the heads up on the title. I've fixed it!

Comment: Hey shapeshifter - I've thought about your helpful information and I'm thinking you're spot on. I'll search Google for some examples, if know of any off the top of your head let me know ;) I'll edit my code with your approach to help mitigate some off topic comments ;)

Comment: shapeshifter, well I did what you said and that's what I needed to do. Answer this so I can give you credit ;)